# Relaxer or JAXB for XML->Object Model?

Tags: java, xml, relaxng, relaxer

I would like generate an AST from my XML-definition, to be used for code generation later on.

The XML schema is written in Relax NG, since it seemed like a neater and more modern than XSD and DTD (loose assumption). I especially fancy the compact syntax, which feels more natural to work with and is far more readable than XML.

Has anyone worked with Relaxer, or any other code generator which works with RelaxNG schemas (preferably the compact ones)? Are they just as good as for example JAXB and Castor, or am I sacrificing some functionality that I will need later on?

After some further research it turns out that JAXB has built in support for RelaxNG, both XML and compact style. Then this must but be the way to go right?

Answer (score 1):

I found that creating classes direct from a RelaxNG schema using JAXB didnt give very readable classes, but if I used http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html to convert RelaxNG to XSD and then generated classes from XSD using JAXB the results were very good.